# Building the source code of WSO2 EI 6.5.0

Tags: wso2

I am trying to build the source code WSO2 EI from https://github.com/wso2/product-ei.git using maven: mvn clean install. But it does not success, there are some bugs as below:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary for WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.6.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) on project org.wso2.carbon.ei.tests.transport: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete D:\wso2-workspace\TestFromGit\product-ei\integration\mediation-tests\tests-transport\target\jacoco\agent\jacocoagent.jar -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) on project org.wso2.carbon.ei.tests.transport: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete D:\wso2-workspace\TestFromGit\product-ei\integration\mediation-tests\tests-transport\target\jacoco\agent\jacocoagent.jar
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete D:\wso2-workspace\TestFromGit\product-ei\integration\mediation-tests\tests-transport\target\jacoco\agent\jacocoagent.jar
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo.execute (CleanMojo.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to delete D:\wso2-workspace\TestFromGit\product-ei\integration\mediation-tests\tests-transport\target\jacoco\agent\jacocoagent.jar
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:251)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo.execute (CleanMojo.java:181)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :org.wso2.carbon.ei.tests.transport
```

I also built the project with maven in Eclipse:

*Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.
Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)
Build id: 20190614-1200
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java version: 1.8.0_221*

But I got the same problem. I already set Java_home (jdk1.8.0_221) and Maven_home. I do not know how to solve this issue, Please give me advice !

Comment: What is the maven version you are using

Comment: Here is the maven version using: Apache Maven 3.6.1 (d66c9c0b3152b2e69ee9bac180bb8fcc8e6af555; 2019-04-05T02:00:29+07:00)
Maven home: D:\Software-Dev\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin\..
Java version: 11.0.4, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.4
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: seems maven is failing in clean phase, i.e in "mvn clean", itself failing . Could you take a new clone and build. Also this is failing while running the tests , if you don't need to run the integration tests , you may skip them . You may use , mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true command

Comment: I used this command and got the error when run the integrator.bat:  TomcatBundleActivator Error while starting server org/apache/xerces/util/SecurityManager.

Comment: I've built this product successfully with release tag: 6.5.0. Thank you for your help!